# Autoadd Foriegn Key value in rails 4

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4

I am very new to rails and am trying to create a small app.  I have 2 tables clients and projects.  I have a jqgrid table that I am using to try to add projects.   My form requests info for the project table and when inserted I would like it to find the client_id by an abbreviation (CLIENT_NM).  Right now when the row is inserted the foreign key value in the clients table is entered as NULL.  How do I have rails update the foreign table (provided the key exists) using the client_nm.

```
The clients table Modes:
class Client < ActiveRecord::Base
  database_connection = Rails.env
  establish_connection database_connection.to_sym
  self.table_name = 'clients'
  has_many :projects, :inverse_of => :client
  #attr_accessible :client_number, :client_mnemonic, :client_name, :client_location
end
```

The actual table:

```
SQL> desc clients
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 ID                                        NOT NULL NUMBER(38)
 CLIENT_MNEMONIC                                    VARCHAR2(255 CHAR)
 CLIENT_NUMBER                                      NUMBER(38)
 CLIENT_NAME                                        VARCHAR2(255 CHAR)
 CLIENT_LOCATION                                    VARCHAR2(255 CHAR)
 CREATED_AT                                         DATE
 UPDATED_AT                                         DATE
```

The projects table:

```
class Project < ActiveRecord::Base
  database_connection = Rails.env
  establish_connection database_connection.to_sym
  self.table_name = 'projects'
  belongs_to :client, :inverse_of => :project
  #attr_accessible :client_number, :client_mnemonic, :client_name, :client_location
end
```

The actual projects table

```
SQL> desc projects
 Name                                      Null?    Type
 ----------------------------------------- -------- ----------------------------
 ID                                        NOT NULL NUMBER(38)
 CLIENT_ID                                          NUMBER(38)
 CLIENT_NM                                          VARCHAR2(255 CHAR)
 PROJECT_NAME                                       VARCHAR2(255 CHAR)
 PROJECT_STATUS                                     VARCHAR2(255 CHAR)
 PROJECT_START                                      DATE
 PROJECT_END                                        DATE
 PROJECT_TYPE                                       VARCHAR2(255 CHAR)
 PROJECT_PLAN                                       VARCHAR2(255 CHAR)
 PROJECT_DESC                                       VARCHAR2(4000 CHAR)
 CREATED_AT                                         DATE
 UPDATED_AT                                         DATE
```

The controller (snippit) :

```
  if params[:id] == "_empty"
    Project.create(:client_id => params[:client_id],
                   :client_nm => params[:client_nm].upcase,
                   :project_name => params[:project_name],
                   :project_status => params[:project_status],
                   :project_start  => params[:project_start].to_date,
                   :project_end => params[:project_end].to_date,
                   :project_type => params[:project_type],
                   :project_plan => params[:project_plan],
                   :project_desc => params[:project_desc])
```

May be helpful also to show the jqgrid post form data:

```
colModel:[
{name:'id',index:'id', hidden:true},
{name:'client_id',index:'client_id', hidden:true},
{name:'client_nm',index:'client_nm', firstsortorder:"asc", width:25,editable:true,editoptions:{size:8}},
{name:'project_name',index:'project_name', width:60, align:"left",editable:true,editoptions:{size:16}},
{name:'project_status',index:'project_status', width:60, align:"left",editable:true,editoptions:{size:16}},
{name:'project_start',index:'project_start', width:60, align:"left",editable:true,editoptions:{size:16,
       dataInit: function(element) {$(element).datepicker({dateFormat: 'yy.mm.dd'})}
}},
{name:'project_end',index:'project_end', width:60, align:"left",editable:true,editoptions:{size:16,
       dataInit: function(element) {$(element).datepicker({dateFormat: 'yy.mm.dd'})}
}},
{name:'project_type',index:'project_type', width:60, align:"left",editable:true,editoptions:{size:16}},
{name:'project_plan',index:'project_plan', width:60, align:"left",editable:true,editoptions:{size:16}},
{name:'project_desc',index:'project_desc', width:60, align:"left",editable:true,editoptions:{size:16}},
{name:'created_at',index:'created_at', hidden:true},
{name:'updated_at',index:'updated_at', hidden:true}
],
```

I think I need (in sudo code)

```
Project.create(:client_id => find(client_by_client_nm(params[:client_nm].upcase),
```

Or something like that.  I am really unsure how the magic happens here.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Think I have this solved

Answer (score 0):

So this may be a hack but I used pluck knowing that I will always only get one record back

```
      if params[:id] == "_empty"
    Project.create(:client_id => Client.where(client_mnemonic: params[:client_nm].upcase).pluck(:id)[0],
...
```

Hope this helps someone.